# Web2Py connecting to Couchbase and exposing a bucket though an API

Tags: couchbase, web2py

I want to expose an couchbase bucket where I save some XML files generated in my web2py application. I know I could maybe use MongoDB but I had a requirement for using Couchbase.

Is there an official connector for Couchbase? I couldn't find it in the DAL documentation.

I am trying this work around that works:

```
from couchbase import Couchbase
cb = Couchbase.connect(bucket='mybucket', host='localhost', port=8091)
#this works but we got a message saying it is depreciated
# DeprecationWarning: Couchbase.connect() is deprecated. Use Bucket() instead
```

But I got a message saying it is depreciated and I should use this instead:

```
cb = Bucket(bucket='mybucket', host='localhost', port=8091)
```

But then I got an error:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'> name 'Bucket' is not defined
```

Any other suggestion , workarounds on Web2Py connecting to couchbase, specially for being exposed by an API? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a web2py issue, as you are not connecting to Couchbase via the web2py DAL but simply using the standard Couchbase Python SDK. It appears you are using version 2.0 of the SDK. The reason for the NameError is that you have not imported `Bucket`. Based on the [documentation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/python-2.0/download-links.html), looks like it should be:

```
from couchbase.bucket import Bucket
cb = Bucket('couchbase://localhost/mybucket')
```

Note, the web2py DAL has partial support for CouchDB, but not for Couchbase. Using the above, you will not be able to use the web2py DAL or any of its related functionality (e.g., `Auth`, `SQLFORM`, `SQLFORM.grid`) in conjunction with Couchbase.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Indeed I also wanted to check if Web2Py really doesn't support Couchbase at all and I got this confirmation here and in another thread. I guess I will be able to move forward with my API exposure using the normal Python SDK connection.

Comment: `localhost:<port>` is deprecated as well, unless `port` is non-standard, in which case `port` would be either `http://<host>:<http_port>` or `couchbase://<host>:<memcached_port>`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like he's using the standard port, so I removed it from the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use the syntax `cb = Bucket(bucket='mybucket', host='localhost', port=8091)` then you will have to update your import statement from `from couchbase import Couchbase` to `from couchbase.bucket import Bucket`.

You should no longer hit a NameError if you update your import statement.

Unfortunately I am not sure that this supports quite what you want it to do with web2py.